# Win32/MFC Get window rect from client rect

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc

I know there is a function somewhere that will accept a client rect and it will convert it into a window rect for you. I just can't find / remember it!

Does anyone know what it is?

It will do something similar to:

```
const CRect client(0, 0, 200, 200);
const CRect window = ClientRectToWindowRect(client);
SetWindowPos(...)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably thinking of [`AdjustWindowRectEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632667(VS.85).aspx). Keep in mind, this is intended for use when *creating* a window - there's no guarantee that it will produce an accurate set of window dimensions for an existing window; for that, use [`GetWindowRect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633519(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

ClientToScreen

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532670(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Nope, that takes client coordinates and converts them to screen coordinates.

Comment: This doesn't account for the window borders. I had the same answer until I realized my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to map client co-ordinates to window co-ordinates use the **ClientToWindow** API.

If you want to map client co-ordinates to screen co-ordinates use the **ClientToScreen** API.

Answer (score 0):

For control reposition use:

```
RECT client;
::SetRect(&client, 0, 0, 200, 200);
::MapWindowPoints(hwndControl, ::GetParent(hwndControl), (POINT*)&client, 2);
::SetWindowPos(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you window rect in client coordinates, so you can use rect(top,left) as offset

```
CRect rectFrame;
GetWindowRect(&rectFrame);
ScreenToClient(&rectFrame);
```