# Getting mouse position in a Windows application

Tags: c++, winapi, coordinates, mouse, directx-11

I'm coding a simple game engine with DirectX11 and I'm using Win32 API to create a window and process user input. I'm implementing a ray casting routine to pick and place entities on a terrain, and all works fine except that when I try to place something on the ground it has a weird offset to the top and to the left:

[image]

After quite a bit of debugging I found out that my code works fine, and the issue is with the window coordinates that I send to the ray casting class/function:

```
LRESULT Game::GameWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
            /*MessageBox(mWindow, L"left mouse button clicked", L"CLICK", MB_OK);*/
            Timer::GetInstance()->Stop();
------->    Input::GetInstance()->Place(lParam & 0xFFFF, lParam >> 16 & 0xFFFF, mCamera, mEntity, mTerrain, mRenderer);
            return 0;
           // ....
           // .... other cases
    }
}
```

The coordinates of the mouse cursor are not between 0 and the window width/height (1024 X 768 in my case), but the maximum width is 1004 and the maximum height is 718 (more or less when I click on the bottom right corner of the window), that's what I read when I debug the application.

A final prove of that is that if I use those width and height in my code, objects are placed where they should. 
So my question is, how come the coordinates don't cover the whole window size? Am I missing something/ doing something wrong? How can I get correct coordinates?

**EDIT**

my function requires client area coordinates, the coordinates of the mouse cursor INSIDE the window, of course.

**EDIT EDIT**

this is the code I use to create the window

```
void Game::InitializeWindow(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASS windowClass = {};
    windowClass.hInstance = hInstance;
    windowClass.lpfnWndProc = &WndProc;
    windowClass.lpszClassName = L"wndClass";
    windowClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    windowClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    windowClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    windowClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    windowClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    windowClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    windowClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(GRAY_BRUSH);
    RegisterClass(&windowClass);

    mWindow = CreateWindow(L"wndClass", L"DirectX 11 Engine", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, DisplayManager::GetInstance()->GetDisplayWidth(), DisplayManager::GetInstance()->GetDisplayHeight(), 0, 0, hInstance, 0);
    if (!mWindow)
        ErrorBox(L"window creation failed");

    ShowWindow(mWindow, SW_SHOW);
    UpdateWindow(mWindow);
}
```

Comment: Maybe the window boundaries are including the window border?

Comment: `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` provides client-based mouse coordinates.  Does `place` also expect client based, or does it want window based coordinates?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm what's the difference? I'm using winapi for the first time, I thought that the message parameter would contain the window coordinates from the top left corner. My function expects those.

Comment: The client coordinates are offset from the window coordinates by the border, title bar, etc.  Usually when you're working in the client area you don't care what the border looks like.  Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140347/win32-mfc-get-window-rect-from-client-rect) can help.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm then how come the top left corner is 0,0 ? If the're offset the origin should be offset as well. It's strange that the top left corner is 0,0 and the bottom right is 1004, 716 instead of 1024,768

Comment: Client area coordinates start at 0,0 (top left). The difference you see in width, height is because window size includes title bar and borders, but client size does not. Call `GetClientRect()` to get client area size.

Comment: @zett42 thanks, that solved my problem, answer my question so I can accept the answer

Comment: @Luca also FYI, don't manually shift the bits of `lParam` to get the coordinates.  Use the `GET_X_LPARAM()`/`GET_Y_LPARAM()` or `MAKEPOINTS()` macros instead, per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645607.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The coordinates you receive from `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` are client coordinates, and are correct. The real issue here stems from the difference between the *window area* and *client area*.

The window area contains the whole window, including the title bar and borders. The `RECT` you would get from `GetWindowRect` is exactly large enough to cover every pixel of your window, such that superimposing a black box of that size on the screen would cause your entire window, title bar and borders included, to disappear.

The client area, however, is the area *inside* the borders Windows creates for you. The `RECT` you would get from `GetClientRect` is just large enough that, again, superimposing a black box of that size on the screen would cover your entire 3D scene, but leave the title bar and borders visible.

The theory and definitions here are all well and good, but now we need to solve the problem. It turns out, the code you have in your window procedure, aside from the API compliance issues noted by Remy Lebeau (use `GET_X_LPARAM()`/`GET_Y_LPARAM()` instead of shifting), is perfectly fine, and needs no modification. The actual point where you introduce the error is during your window creation code.

The `nWidth` and `nHeight` parameters to `CreateWindow` specify the width and height of the *window*, not the client area. As such, your client area will be smaller. However, you want the client area to have those widths.

Turns out, this is such a common occurence that Windows 2000 added a function to generate the proper window width and height for a given client area: `AdjustWindowRect`. To use it, change your `CreateWindow` call to the following:

```
RECT windowRect;
windowRect.top = 0;
windowRect.left = 0;
windowRect.right = DisplayManager::GetInstance()->GetDisplayWidth();
windowRect.bottom = DisplayManager::GetInstance()->GetDisplayHeight();

AdjustWindowRect(&windowRect, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, FALSE);

mWindow = CreateWindow(L"wndClass", 
                       L"DirectX 11 Engine", 
                       WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 
                       CW_USEDEFAULT, 
                       CW_USEDEFAULT, 
                       windowRect.right, 
                       windowRect.bottom, 
                       0, 
                       0, 
                       hInstance, 
                       0);
```

This will offset your coordinates to ensure that the client area is exactly the size the DisplayManager thinks it should be.

**EDIT**

If you have an extended window style, `AdjustWindowRectEx` allows you to specify those extended window styles as an additional fourth argument to the function.